# Symfony 4 Simplify condition code in controller?

Tags: symfony

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    if (false === $this->isGranted('USER_EDIT_PROFILE', $user)) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Message');
        return $this->redirect($this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->headers->get('referer'));
    }

    return $this->render('admin/user/edit.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

Any suggestions for optimizing such expressions? You can make a method,

```
    if (false === $this->isGranted('USER_EDIT_PROFILE', $user)) {
        return $this->denyAccessRedirect('Message');
    }
```

but it still requires more code than

```
$this->denyAccessRedirect('Message');
```

The problem is that the controller must return a response. And the method is called without **return**

Comment: you're slightly wrong, a method doesn't have to return a response, it also can throw an exception, see this standard controller method which will probably help a lot ;o) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3be177a93f75ccc0dc554057df04a8b9ea4869fb/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L190 ... also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#setup-checking-for-access-in-a-controller

Comment: to reiterate: the exceptions are then handled by an exception controller which produces some kind of more or less helpful error message and redirects to the login page, afaik. you can of course implement your own controller to handle those ;o)

Comment: I already read about it. denyAccessUnlessGranted makes a redirect to the app_login, then to the app_home one. I do not need it. But I did not understand how to create my simple exception. The exception is mainly thrown as a system text instead of a redirect to the desired route

Comment: you could throw a custom exception and catch it in a special kernel request handler to show it on the same page. although it's not really clear, how that would technically work ... or you could wrap the function content in a try-catch block and do it right there ...

Comment: What if there is no referer?

Comment: A referrer 100% must exist. Editing is in progress, you cannot redirect without displaying the form. So there will be a referrer to the current page